# Perl getting segmentation fault while timeout using alarm

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, timeout, alarm

I'm writing Perl for the first time and Internet tells me i can use alarm if i have a long running sql query.
I need to run a SP which will run for hours in a Perl, and i would like to set a time limit.
Below is the last step of my codes but i'm getting **segmentation fault** when the process runs longer that my timeout, in this occasion sleep(20). Logs shows it finished printing ---1---- and then segmentation fault.
How can I fix this?

I tried taking sub DelRef{} out into a seperate .pl and comment the $db part in the third line to test if alarm is working fine, and it worked all right. I'm confused which part went wrong and caused the segmentation fault.

```
sub DelRef {
    print "starting defRefData\n";
    $db = new Sybapi($user, $password, $server, $margin_database);
    print "entering eval\n";
    my $timeout = 10;
    eval {
            local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout\n" };
            print "inside eval now\n";
            alarm($timeout);
            print "---1----\n";
            #sleep(5); --working fine
            sleep(20); #not working, 
            #$db->exec_sql("exec CPN_Margins..clean_up_refData_db '$XrefCode'");
            print "----2----\n";
            alarm(0);
    };
    #alarm(0);
            print "out of eval\n";
    if($@)
    {
        #die unless $@ eq "timeout\n";
        if($@ =~ "timeout\n")
        {
        warn "Timed out!\n";
        #exit 0;
        }
        else{
                print $@;
        }
    }

}

&DelRef();
print "process is done\n";
$db->close();
```

Comment: Presumably, the C code in Sybapi mishandles the error that occurs when a signal happens during some system calls. (Signals cause blocking system calls to return with `EINTR` to give signal handlers a chance to run.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get out of this. You didn't even a question, for starters.

Comment: So i shouldn't be using Sybapi? I want to how i can fix this segmentation fault.

Comment: If you want more than  "don't use `alarm` and Sybapi together", you're asking how to debug C code. That's rather far beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

From perldoc (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)-

> It is usually a mistake to intermix alarm and sleep calls, because
>   sleep may be internally implemented on your system with alarm.

If you want to implement timeout, it can be achieved without sleep. Just follow the example mentioned in the link.

EDIT:
I have added it here -[How to set timeout for a long running Sybase sp in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146492/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-long-running-sybase-sp-in-perl/58147155#58147155)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question. The OP's `sleep` clearly doesn't rely on `alarm`, and the OP is specifically not having the problem he's asking about when using `sleep` instead of the slow DB call.