# How to set timeout for a long running Sybase sp in Perl

Tags: perl, timeout, sybase

I'm calling a stored procedure which deletes data from Sybase DB in a Perl. But the sp takes hours to complete.
I just want the sp to run for 1 hour, then no matter whether it completes or not I want the codes afterwards to be running. How can I implement this?

```
sub DelRef {
    print "starting defRefData\n";
    $db = new Sybapi($user, $password, $server, $margin_database); 
    #the following sql will take hours
    $db->exec_sql("exec CPN_Margins..clean_up_refData_db '$XrefCode'");
}

&DelRef();
print "process is done\n";
$db->close();
```

Comment: What is `Sybapi`? I cannot find it on CPAN. Are you actually using `DBD::Sybase` to connect the database?

Comment: It is something developed by our own. I haven't tried DBD::Sybase.

Comment: What are you learning from that says to call subroutines via a leading `&`?

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to delete data from your Sybase database in much smaller chunks so that no query takes so long that you overshoot your time window. While you're at it, use DBD::Sybase from CPAN; it may not be better behaved, but it's probably better understood by the community than an in-house sybase driver.

Comment: Is the stored proc running a single query for a lengthy period of time, or is it running some sort of cursor/looping process?  If the former, have you done any P&T analysis to find out if 'long running' is expected?  if the latter, consider passing the time to the stored proc, then on each pass through the cursor/loop test the difference between the 'start' and 'current' time to see if you've hit your max (and if so then break out of the loop); granted, this won't help if you determine the run time *after* the proc has been called ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm always wary of using `alarm` to interrupt a system call, as I find it hard to predict when the signal will be ignored [or worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144739/perl-getting-segmentation-fault-while-timeout-using-alarm).

An alternative is to run your long-running code in a background process, and monitor its progress in the main process.

```
# DelRef() might take a while ...
my $start_time = time;
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    # child process
    DelRef();
    exit 0;
}
# parent process
while (1) {
    use POSIX qw( WNOHANG );
    my $waitpid = waitpid $pid, WNOHANG;
    if ($pid == $waitpid) {
        print STDERR "DelRef() finished successfully\n";
        last;
    }
    if (time - $start_time > 3600) {
        print STDERR "DelRef() didn't finish in an hour\n";
        kill 'TERM',$pid;    # optional
        last;
    }
    print STDERR "DelRef() is still running ...\n";
    sleep 60;
}
print STDERR "... the rest of the script ...\n";
```

Comment: Tip: You normally want to follow up a TERM signal with a KILL signal if the process is still running after it should have had long enough to exit. (But it's not necessary to demonstrate that here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'alarm' for this https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html

```
    my $timeout = 3600; # 1hr = 3600 sec
    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
        alarm $timeout;
        $db = new Sybapi($user, $password, $server, $margin_database); 
        $db->exec_sql("exec CPN_Margins..clean_up_refData_db '$XrefCode'");
        alarm 0;
    };
    if ($@) {
        die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
        # timed out
    }
    else {
        # didn't timed out
    }
```

Also what is 'Sybapi'? In the past I have use 'DBD::Sybase' to connect to Sybase ASE(or 'sybperl' in old legacy code), and 'DBD::SQLAnywhere' to connect to [Sybase IQ](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1601/doc/html/san1357754962101.html).

Comment: Isn't this precisely their previous question (which you answered?), on how this doesn't work?

Comment: sl266 has previously posted that this results in a segfault.